# Can I compute with float and double on a Pi pico?

Tags: pi-pico

I did not see float capabilities on cortex M0+, is it possible anyway ?

The Pico sdk provides float capabilities: did I misread about the M0+ or is it done in some way ? How ?

https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__pico__float.html#details

Comment: I'm not sure about the hardware capabilities, but if the CPU has no floating point unit, the compiler will emulate these operations. That's fully transparent for you (except that it is slow)

Comment: in addition to above: see Pico SDK docs for more info on floating point support

Comment: The Raspberry Pi Pico Technical Specification states "Accelerated floating-point libraries on-chip"

Comment: Your question is vague and provides no evidence of any problem. It actually contains the answer, but you do not appear to have tried it.

Comment: @Milliways The questions are unambiguous and specific. If something is not clear to you, please be specific about it, so I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do float calculation with M0+ despite the lack for float registers, but it is very slow.

> Both Keil and gcc-arm supports floating point operations in software
> without floating point hardware. For gcc see
> http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html, -mfloat-abi
> option. In Keil no compiler options has to be set as far as I know.
>
> Your code does not have to consider if the floating point calculations
> are done in software or hardware. Example:

```
float a,b,c;
 
a = 3.14; b = 2.73; c = a * b;
```

> Note that due to the lack of a FPU, floating point operations are very
> slow compared to integer operations.

https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/411/floating-point-on-a-cortex-m0